# How to solve the error "could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" after trying to install requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pip

After updating Python to the latest version, previous files were over-written and I was left with this error when trying to run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

> Processing /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot1/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot1/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-124/altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

How would one go about solving or understanding the approach to fixing this issue? I am not quite sure where to begin, so any help would be really appreciated.

I should be expecting the line to run without any errors and the web app should be able to run as well, but I encountered the previous error.

When I ran:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I encountered this error too:

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

The virtual environment is indeed active, my problem is trying to download all the requirements and encountering the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

The path seems to be an absolute path on your local system. This can be a problem when using `requirements.txt` in different environments.
I would change the requirements.txt file to include a version specifier rather than an absolute path. You can try `altgraph==0.17.2`

How would I approach the problem, firstly I would clean the cache with `pip cache purge`, and I would delete all the absolute paths and pass them as in the previous example with `altgraph`. Ensure all dependencies listed in your requirements.txt are installed. The Django error might be a follow-up issue if some dependencies fail to install.